# Ошибка в Koala! ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 Use --trace for backtrace

Tags: css, sass

ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
Use --trace for backtrace
Как исправить эту ошибку ?

Comment: @MedvedevDev: Напишите это же ответом, и гугл будет приводить теперь именно к нему!

Comment: А глупых вопросов не бывает

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в русских буквах в пути к файлу. Решение: откат к версии 2.1.4 либо изменение кириллицы на латиницу в пути к файлу.

Answer (score 0):

B настройки Win-10 ввести изменение:
Параметры Windows > Время и язык > Язык > Административные языковые параметры > Нажать кнопку: Изменить язык системы > Поставить галочку: Бета-версия:. Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире.

Тогда заработает.